# Firebase 'to' send to everyone in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I have topics to send push notifications. In particular

- `all`: this is a topic in which I send notifications to **everyone**
- `paid`: this is a topic in which I send notification only to a small group of users

Today I was upgrading Flutter to the newest firebase package and I encountered this:

```
<String, dynamic>{
 'notification': <String, dynamic>{
   'body': 'this is a body',
   'title': 'this is a title'
 },
 'priority': 'high',
 'data': <String, dynamic>{
   'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
   'id': '1',
   'status': 'done'
  },
  'to': await firebaseMessaging.getToken(),
},
```

But wait, isn't `'to'` meant to send notifications only to a specific device? Why does

```
'to': await firebaseMessaging.getToken(),
```

this send a message to all devices? I am confused because the doc says that 'to' is for specific targets too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to` property in an FCM message determines where it is sent to. The value of the `to` property can be the device token of a single device, it can be the ID of a device group, or it can be a topic.

It sounds like in your actual code you pass a topic in `to`, while in the sample in your question it passes a device token.

Comment: Well, the documentation says that 'getToken()' returns the FCM token. So I guess that's why it sends the notification to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Firestore api by google to send push notifications

```
Future<bool> callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications(List <String> userToken) async 
{

  final postUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  final data = {
    "registration_ids" : userToken,
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "notification" : {
      "title": 'NewTextTitle',
      "body" : 'NewTextBody',
    }
  };

  final headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': constant.firebaseTokenAPIFCM // 'key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY'
  };

  final response = await http.post(postUrl,
      body: json.encode(data),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
      headers: headers);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     // on success do sth
    print('test ok push CFM');
    return true;
  } else {
    print(' CFM error');
    // on failure do sth
      return false;
  }
}
```